# PyQt-Thread restart

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyqt4

Is there a possibility to "really" restart a PyQt-Thread?

I am starting some processes with the multiprocessing libary in this thread and want to restart these processes with new input datas by restarting the thread.

Comment: no, you jhave to stop it manually then `.run` it again

Comment: What do you mean by "really"? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: When i terminate and start the process there are some datas left in the memory. I now tested to restart the program with subprocess.Popen, but i can use this function one time only (the second time the programm crashs).

Comment: @Weevil. I doubt whether anyone can help with this unless you edit your question and add a [mcve].